# How to set a GCS object lifecycle for all objects below a path, not bucket-wide?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) only mention setting an object lifecycle for an entire bucket. However I want to set lifecycles for several paths within a bucket, but not for the entire bucket.

Is this possible on Google Cloud Storage? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to configure lifecycle management for less than an entire bucket.

Comment: I know this is a very old question and answer from 2016, but is it still the same? Can we control object lifecycle on a specific path or specific objects in GCS bucket? I didn't find any documentation related to path.

Comment: +Balkrishan Aggarwal lifecycle management still can only be defined at the level of an entire bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#introduction

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to achieve is having a lifecycle rule restricted to only certain subpaths. You can achieve this by setting *Conditions* on the rule.

Object lifecycle rules can combine multiple conditions. If you want a certain lifecycle to be applied only to a specific sub-path of the bucket, you can combine the condition you want to apply to that sub-path the condition *matches prefix*.

For example, if you want to set the object storage class to Nearline only for objects in the sub-path `goToNearline/`, you can achive this by creating a lifecycle rule like the following:

[image: How to "restrict" a lifecycle rule to certain sub-paths]

Yes, the lifecycle rule is still applied to the bucket-level, but the condition restricts its application, so this is virtually equivalent to having it set only for a specific sub-path.